# Login on my web site following login on Twitter/Facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, passport.js, twitter-oauth

I have a [follow button of Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button/parameters) and a [like button of Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) on my `mean-stack` webpage.

I have also a login system implemented by `passport.js` in the webpage, people can login via social accounts such as Google, Twitter and Facebook.

For a user who has not signed in on my webpage or Twitter. If he clicks on the follow button of Twitter, a window of Twitter will popup and ask him to log in. After this login, does anyone know **if it is possible to make the user systemically signed in on my website too?**

Same question applies to Facebook too.

Comment: Depends, did they already login to your app before? At least for Facebook, recurring users can be recognized automatically by the JS SDK.

Comment: It is possible that a use had signed in my app before by Facebook ID, but he has not liked my company and has not signed in this session. So what could we do? Do you have any link about recognising recurring users automatically by JS SDK?

Comment: What does liking your company have to do with anything? // The JS SDK does that automatically on each page load (unless you specifically instructed it not to do so via parameter.)